# How to create column that measures the number of occurrences in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, query-optimization

I am trying to count the number of unique occurrences of a certain column - "car_id" For example, if Car_Shop_A has 3 occurrences of a certain car_id I would like this count to be displayed in the table like so: *"Shop1 - car_1 - 3"*

```
SELECT
    shop_name,
    car_id,
    Count(car_id) as count
    
FROM
    car_database
WHERE
    date between '20210101' AND '2021131'
    AND shop_name IN ('Shop1',
                        'Shop2',
                        'Shop3',
                        'Shop4',
                        'Shop5',
                        'Shop6')
                        
                                
group by shop_name, car_id
order by count desc
```

The above is my current query, however it returns this table:

[image: Unintended query result]

This query returns the same count for all shops and returns the number of rows rather than the number of each car_id occurrence. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, removing the car_id column from the grouping and adding DISTINCT to the count function should return the result you need:

```sql
SELECT
    shop_name,
    Count(distinct car_id) as count
    
FROM
    car_database
WHERE
    date between '20210101' AND '2021131'
    AND shop_name IN ('Shop1',
                        'Shop2',
                        'Shop3',
                        'Shop4',
                        'Shop5',
                        'Shop6')
                        
                                
group by shop_name
order by count desc
```

Comment: I am trying to include the car_id column too, to see how many times a specific car appears in the respective shop - would I include car_id in the grouping in this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    shop_name || ' - ' || car_id || ' - ' || count(1) as shop_car_listing
FROM
    car_database
WHERE
    date between '20210101' AND '2021131'
    AND shop_name IN ('Shop1',
                      'Shop2',
                      'Shop3',
                      'Shop4',
                      'Shop5',
                      'Shop6')                              
group by shop_name, car_id 
order by count(1) desc
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=820d70b0da7d75c6729736edb1ac8f4f)

Comment: The string concatenation operator in SQL is `||` - `+` is used to add numbers. There is also no `nvarchar(max)` in Postgres

Comment: sorry i used sql server didn't pay attention to postgres. give me a second